# OAuth with mongoDb in yii2

Tags: mongodb, oauth-2.0, yii2

I was trying to use Aouth2 to secure api's with mongoDB and yii2. but unable to connect Aouth with mongoDB. Anybody have idea how to use mongoDB as storage for oauth2 in yii2.
Your help will be appreciated.
Thank you
code flow is as under

config file :

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['oauth2'],
    'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
        ],
        'oauth2' => [
            'class' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\Module',
            'tokenParamName' => 'accessToken',
            'tokenAccessLifetime' => 3600 * 24,
            'storageMap' => [
                'user_credentials' => 'common\models\Users',
                'refresh_token' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
                'access_token' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
                'client' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
                'authorization_code' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
                'client_credentials' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
                'public_key' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
                'jwt_bearer' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
                'scope' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
            ],
            'grantTypes' => [
                'user_credentials' => [
                    'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials',
                ],
                'refresh_token' => [
                    'class' => 'OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken',
                    'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Storgage/Mongo.php file

```
namespace filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage;

class Mongo extends \OAuth2\Storage\Mongo
{
    protected $db;
    protected $config;

    public function __construct($connection, $config = array())
    {
//         print_r($connection);
        if ($connection instanceof MongoDB) {

            $this->db = $connection;
        }
        else {
            if (!is_array($connection)) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('First argument to OAuth2_Storage_Mongo must be an instance of MongoDB or a configuration array');
            }
            $server = sprintf('mongodb://%s:%d', "localhost", "27017");
            $m = new MongoClient($server);
            $this->db = $m->{"test"};
        }

        // Unix timestamps might get larger than 32 bits,
        // so let's add native support for 64 bit ints.
        ini_set('mongo.native_long', 1);

        $this->config = array_merge(array(
            'client_table' => 'oauth_clients',
            'access_token_table' => 'oauth_access_tokens',
            'refresh_token_table' => 'oauth_refresh_tokens',
            'code_table' => 'oauth_authorization_codes',
            'user_table' => 'oauth_users',
            'jwt_table' => 'oauth_jwt',
        ), $config);
    }

    // Helper function to access a MongoDB collection by `type`:
    protected function collection($name)
    {
        return $this->db->{$this->config[$name]};
    }

    /* ClientCredentialsInterface */
    public function checkClientCredentials($client_id, $client_secret = null)
    {
        $result = $this->collection('client_table')->findOne(array('client_id' => $client_id));

        return $result['client_secret'] == $client_secret;
    }

    public function getClientDetails($client_id)
    {
        $result = $this->collection('client_table')->findOne(array('client_id' => $client_id));

        return is_null($result) ? false : $result;
    }

    public function checkRestrictedGrantType($client_id, $grant_type)
    {
        $details = $this->getClientDetails($client_id);
        if (isset($details['grant_types'])) {
            return in_array($grant_type, (array) $details['grant_types']);
        }

        // if grant_types are not defined, then none are restricted
        return true;
    }

    /* AccessTokenInterface */
    public function getAccessToken($access_token)
    {
        $token = $this->collection('access_token_table')->findOne(array('access_token' => $access_token));

        return is_null($token) ? false : $token;
    }

    public function setAccessToken($access_token, $client_id, $user_id, $expires, $scope = null)
    {
        // if it exists, update it.
        if ($this->getAccessToken($access_token)) {
            $this->collection('access_token_table')->update(
                array('access_token' => $access_token),
                array('$set' => array(
                    'client_id' => $client_id,
                    'expires' => $expires,
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'scope' => $scope
                ))
            );
        } else {
            $this->collection('access_token_table')->insert(
                array(
                    'access_token' => $access_token,
                    'client_id' => $client_id,
                    'expires' => $expires,
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'scope' => $scope
                )
            );
        }

        return true;
    }


    /* AuthorizationCodeInterface */
    public function getAuthorizationCode($code)
    {
        $code = $this->collection('code_table')->findOne(array('authorization_code' => $code));

        return is_null($code) ? false : $code;
    }

    public function setAuthorizationCode($code, $client_id, $user_id, $redirect_uri, $expires, $scope = null, $token_id = null)
    {
        // if it exists, update it.
        if ($this->getAuthorizationCode($code)) {
            $this->collection('code_table')->update(
                array('authorization_code' => $code),
                array('$set' => array(
                    'client_id' => $client_id,
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
                    'expires' => $expires,
                    'scope' => $scope
                ))
            );
        } else {
            $this->collection('code_table')->insert(
                array(
                    'authorization_code' => $code,
                    'client_id' => $client_id,
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
                    'expires' => $expires,
                    'scope' => $scope
                )
            );
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function expireAuthorizationCode($code)
    {
        $this->collection('code_table')->remove(array('authorization_code' => $code));

        return true;
    }


    /* UserCredentialsInterface */
    public function checkUserCredentials($username, $password)
    {
        if ($user = $this->getUser($username)) {
            return $this->checkPassword($user, $password);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getUserDetails($username)
    {
        if ($user = $this->getUser($username)) {
            $user['user_id'] = $user['username'];
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /* RefreshTokenInterface */
    public function getRefreshToken($refresh_token)
    {

        $token = $this->collection('refresh_token_table')->findOne(array('refresh_token' => $refresh_token));

        return is_null($token) ? false : $token;
    }

    public function setRefreshToken($refresh_token, $client_id, $user_id, $expires, $scope = null)
    {

        $this->collection('refresh_token_table')->insert(
            array(
                'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
                'client_id' => $client_id,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'expires' => $expires,
                'scope' => $scope
            )
        );

        return true;
    }

    public function unsetRefreshToken($refresh_token)
    {
        $this->collection('refresh_token_table')->remove(array('refresh_token' => $refresh_token));

        return true;
    }


    // plaintext passwords are bad!  Override this for your application
    protected function checkPassword($user, $password)
    {
        return $user['password'] == $password;
    }

    public function getUser($username)
    {
        $result = $this->collection('user_table')->findOne(array('username' => $username));

        return is_null($result) ? false : $result;
    }

    public function setUser($username, $password, $firstName = null, $lastName = null)
    {
        if ($this->getUser($username)) {
            $this->collection('user_table')->update(
                array('username' => $username),
                array('$set' => array(
                    'password' => $password,
                    'first_name' => $firstName,
                    'last_name' => $lastName
                ))
            );
        } else {
            $this->collection('user_table')->insert(
                array(
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password,
                    'first_name' => $firstName,
                    'last_name' => $lastName
                )
            );
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function getClientKey($client_id, $subject)
    {
        $result = $this->collection('jwt_table')->findOne(array(
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'subject' => $subject
        ));

        return $result;
    }
}
```

... Error It showing is

```
{
  "name": "Invalid Configuration",
  "message": "Missing required parameter \"connection\" when instantiating \"filsh\\yii2\\oauth2server\\storage\\Mongo\".",
  "code": 0,
  "type": "yii\\base\\InvalidConfigException",
  "file": "/var/www/html/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php",
  "line": 457,
  "stack-trace": [
    "#0 /var/www/html/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(367): yii\\di\\Container->resolveDependencies(Array, Object(ReflectionClass))",
    "#1 /var/www/html/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(154): yii\\di\\Container->build('filsh\\yii2\\oaut...', Array, Array)",
    "#2 /var/www/html/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(172): yii\\di\\Container->get('filsh\\yii2\\oaut...', Array, Array)",
    "#3 /var/www/html/advanced/vendor/filsh/yii2-oauth2-server/Module.php(80): yii\\di\\Container->get('refresh_token')",
    "#4 /var/www/html/advanced/vendor/filsh/yii2-oauth2-server/controllers/RestController.php(25): filsh\\yii2\\oauth2server\\Module->getServer()",
    "#5 [internal function]: filsh\\yii2\\oauth2server\\controllers\\RestController->actionToken()",
    "#6 /var/www/html/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)",
    "#7 /var/www/html/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(154): yii\\base\\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)",
    "#8 /var/www/html/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(454): yii\\base\\Controller->runAction('token', Array)",
    "#9 /var/www/html/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(87): yii\\base\\Module->runAction('oauth2/rest/tok...', Array)",
    "#10 /var/www/html/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\\web\\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\\web\\Request))",
    "#11 /var/www/html/advanced/api/web/index.php(19): yii\\base\\Application->run()",
    "#12 {main}"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please, provide more information for your case. What's go wrong?

Comment: @ZhukovRA I have edited my question please review it

Answer (score 0):

I think, that your mistake is in module configuration:

```
            'refresh_token' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
            'access_token' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
            'client' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
            'authorization_code' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
            'client_credentials' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
            'public_key' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
            'jwt_bearer' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
            'scope' => 'filsh\yii2\oauth2server\storage\Mongo',
```

You do not need this strings. Please read installing instructions in [official github repo](https://github.com/Filsh/yii2-oauth2-server). Your `User` class must use MongoDb connection, if you want use MongoDb.

Answer (score -2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLwAB.png)
This is my modified "OAuth with mongoDb in yii2" mongoDb connection scheme, which can be used normally after testing.Here is my code: By KuangFeng

```
<?php

namespace app\components\oauth2\storage;

use MongoDB\Client;
use MongoDB\Database;
use MongoDB\Driver\Manager;
use yii\helpers\Json;

/**
 * Simple MongoDB storage for all storage types
 *
 * NOTE: This class is meant to get users started
 * quickly. If your application requires further
 * customization, extend this class or create your own.
 *
 * NOTE: Passwords are stored in plaintext, which is never
 * a good idea.  Be sure to override this for your application
 *
 * @author Julien Chaumond <chaumond@gmail.com>
 */
class MongoDB extends \OAuth2\Storage\MongoDB
{
    protected $db;
    protected $config;
    protected $connect = 'mongodb';

    public function __construct($connection = [], $config = array())
    {

        if (empty($connection)) {
            $connection = \Yii::$app->get($this->connect);
        }

        if ($connection instanceof Database) {
            $this->db = $connection;
        } else {
            if (!is_object($connection) && !is_array($connection)) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('First argument to OAuth2\Storage\Mongo must be an instance of MongoDB\Database or a configuration array');
            }
            $dsn = $connection->dsn;
            $hostAndDb = explode("@", $dsn)[1];
            $temp = explode('/', $hostAndDb);
            $db = $temp[1];
            $hostAndPort = $temp[0];
            $username = $connection->options['username'];
            $password = $connection->options['password'];
            //$server = sprintf('mongodb://@%s', $hostAndDb);
            $server = $connection->dsn;
            $m = new Client($server,['username' => $username,'password' => $password]);
            $this->db = $m->selectDatabase($db);

        }
        $this->config = array_merge(array(
            'client_table' => 'oauth_clients',
            'access_token_table' => 'oauth_access_tokens',
            'refresh_token_table' => 'oauth_refresh_tokens',
            'code_table' => 'oauth_authorization_codes',
            'user_table' => 'oauth_users',
            'jwt_table' => 'oauth_jwt',
            'jti_table' => 'oauth_jti',
            'scope_table' => 'oauth_scopes',
            'key_table' => 'oauth_keys',
        ), $config);
    }

    /* ClientCredentialsInterface */
    public function checkClientCredentials($client_id, $client_secret = null)
    {
        if ($result = $this->collection('client_table')->findOne(array('client_id' => $client_id))) {
            return $result['client_secret'] == $client_secret;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function isPublicClient($client_id)
    {
        if (!$result = $this->collection('client_table')->findOne(array('client_id' => $client_id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return empty($result['client_secret']);
    }

    /* ClientInterface */
    public function getClientDetails($client_id)
    {
        $result = $this->collection('client_table')->findOne(array('client_id' => $client_id));
        return is_null($result) ? false : $result;
    }

    public function setClientDetails($client_id, $client_secret = null, $redirect_uri = null, $grant_types = null, $scope = null, $user_id = null)
    {
        if ($this->getClientDetails($client_id)) {
            $result = $this->collection('client_table')->updateOne(
                array('client_id' => $client_id),
                array('$set' => array(
                    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
                    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
                    'grant_types' => $grant_types,
                    'scope' => $scope,
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                ))
            );
            return $result->getMatchedCount() > 0;
        }
        $client = array(
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $client_secret,
            'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
            'grant_types' => $grant_types,
            'scope' => $scope,
            'user_id' => $user_id,
        );
        $result = $this->collection('client_table')->insertOne($client);
        return $result->getInsertedCount() > 0;
    }

    public function checkRestrictedGrantType($client_id, $grant_type)
    {
        $details = $this->getClientDetails($client_id);
        if (isset($details['grant_types'])) {
            $grant_types = explode(' ', $details['grant_types']);
            return in_array($grant_type, $grant_types);
        }
        // if grant_types are not defined, then none are restricted
        return true;
    }

    /* AccessTokenInterface */
    public function getAccessToken($access_token)
    {
        $token = $this->collection('access_token_table')->findOne(array('access_token' => $access_token));
        return is_null($token) ? false : $token;
    }

    public function setAccessToken($access_token, $client_id, $user_id, $expires, $scope = null)
    {
        // if it exists, update it.
        if ($this->getAccessToken($access_token)) {
            $result = $this->collection('access_token_table')->updateOne(
                array('access_token' => $access_token),
                array('$set' => array(
                    'client_id' => $client_id,
                    'expires' => $expires,
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'scope' => $scope,
                ))
            );
            return $result->getMatchedCount() > 0;
        }
        $token = array(
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'expires' => $expires,
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'scope' => $scope,
        );
        $result = $this->collection('access_token_table')->insertOne($token);
        return $result->getInsertedCount() > 0;
    }

    public function unsetAccessToken($access_token)
    {
        $result = $this->collection('access_token_table')->deleteOne(array(
            'access_token' => $access_token,
        ));
        return $result->getDeletedCount() > 0;
    }

    /* AuthorizationCodeInterface */
    public function getAuthorizationCode($code)
    {
        $code = $this->collection('code_table')->findOne(array(
            'authorization_code' => $code,
        ));
        return is_null($code) ? false : $code;
    }

    public function setAuthorizationCode($code, $client_id, $user_id, $redirect_uri, $expires, $scope = null, $id_token = null)
    {
        // if it exists, update it.
        if ($this->getAuthorizationCode($code)) {
            $result = $this->collection('code_table')->updateOne(
                array('authorization_code' => $code),
                array('$set' => array(
                    'client_id' => $client_id,
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
                    'expires' => $expires,
                    'scope' => $scope,
                    'id_token' => $id_token,
                ))
            );
            return $result->getMatchedCount() > 0;
        }
        $token = array(
            'authorization_code' => $code,
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
            'expires' => $expires,
            'scope' => $scope,
            'id_token' => $id_token,
        );
        $result = $this->collection('code_table')->insertOne($token);
        return $result->getInsertedCount() > 0;
    }

    public function expireAuthorizationCode($code)
    {
        $result = $this->collection('code_table')->deleteOne(array(
            'authorization_code' => $code,
        ));
        return $result->getDeletedCount() > 0;
    }

    /* UserCredentialsInterface */
    public function checkUserCredentials($username, $password)
    {
        if ($user = $this->getUser($username)) {
            return $this->checkPassword($user, $password);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getUserDetails($username)
    {
        if ($user = $this->getUser($username)) {
            $user['user_id'] = $user['username'];
        }
        return $user;
    }

    /* RefreshTokenInterface */
    public function getRefreshToken($refresh_token)
    {
        $token = $this->collection('refresh_token_table')->findOne(array(
            'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
        ));
        return is_null($token) ? false : $token;
    }

    public function setRefreshToken($refresh_token, $client_id, $user_id, $expires, $scope = null)
    {
        $token = array(
            'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'expires' => $expires,
            'scope' => $scope,
        );
        $result = $this->collection('refresh_token_table')->insertOne($token);
        return $result->getInsertedCount() > 0;
    }

    public function unsetRefreshToken($refresh_token)
    {
        $result = $this->collection('refresh_token_table')->deleteOne(array(
            'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
        ));
        return $result->getDeletedCount() > 0;
    }

    // plaintext passwords are bad!  Override this for your application
    protected function checkPassword($user, $password)
    {
        return $user['password'] == $password;
    }

    public function getUser($username)
    {
        $result = $this->collection('user_table')->findOne(array('username' => $username));
        return is_null($result) ? false : $result;
    }

    public function setUser($username, $password, $firstName = null, $lastName = null)
    {
        if ($this->getUser($username)) {
            $result = $this->collection('user_table')->updateOne(
                array('username' => $username),
                array('$set' => array(
                    'password' => $password,
                    'first_name' => $firstName,
                    'last_name' => $lastName,
                ))
            );

            return $result->getMatchedCount() > 0;
        }

        $user = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'first_name' => $firstName,
            'last_name' => $lastName,
        );
        $result = $this->collection('user_table')->insertOne($user);
        return $result->getInsertedCount() > 0;
    }

    public function getClientKey($client_id, $subject)
    {
        $result = $this->collection('jwt_table')->findOne(array(
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'subject' => $subject,
        ));
        return is_null($result) ? false : $result['key'];
    }

    public function getClientScope($client_id)
    {
        if (!$clientDetails = $this->getClientDetails($client_id)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($clientDetails['scope'])) {
            return $clientDetails['scope'];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getJti($client_id, $subject, $audience, $expires, $jti)
    {
        //TODO: Needs mongodb implementation.
        throw new \Exception('getJti() for the MongoDB driver is currently unimplemented.');
    }

    public function setJti($client_id, $subject, $audience, $expires, $jti)
    {
        //TODO: Needs mongodb implementation.
        throw new \Exception('setJti() for the MongoDB driver is currently unimplemented.');
    }

    public function getPublicKey($client_id = null)
    {
        if ($client_id) {
            $result = $this->collection('key_table')->findOne(array(
                'client_id' => $client_id,
            ));
            if ($result) {
                return $result['public_key'];
            }
        }

        $result = $this->collection('key_table')->findOne(array(
            'client_id' => null,
        ));
        return is_null($result) ? false : $result['public_key'];
    }

    public function getPrivateKey($client_id = null)
    {
        if ($client_id) {
            $result = $this->collection('key_table')->findOne(array(
                'client_id' => $client_id,
            ));
            if ($result) {
                return $result['private_key'];
            }
        }

        $result = $this->collection('key_table')->findOne(array(
            'client_id' => null,
        ));
        return is_null($result) ? false : $result['private_key'];
    }

    public function getEncryptionAlgorithm($client_id = null)
    {
        if ($client_id) {
            $result = $this->collection('key_table')->findOne(array(
                'client_id' => $client_id,
            ));
            if ($result) {
                return $result['encryption_algorithm'];
            }
        }

        $result = $this->collection('key_table')->findOne(array(
            'client_id' => null,
        ));
        return is_null($result) ? 'RS256' : $result['encryption_algorithm'];
    }

    // Helper function to access a MongoDB collection by `type`:
    protected function collection($name)
    {
        return $this->db->{$this->config[$name]};
    }
}
```